# SIG_IGN fails to ignore SIGINT signal

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

I have a main process and some child process spawn from it. At a point of time i have to give SIGINT signal to all the child process but not to main process. I am unable to store pid's for all child processes. So i used SIG_IGN for ignoring SIGINT in main process and set to default after my action. But it is not working.

Please find my code snippet below:

```
    /* Find group id for process */
    nPgid = getpgid(parentPID);

    /* Ignore SIGINT signal in parent process */
    if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        cout << "Error in ignoring signal \n");
    }

    /* Send SIGINT signal to all process in the group */
    nReturnValue = kill ( (-1 * nPgid), SIGINT);
    if (nReturnValue == RETURN_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Sent SIGINT signal to all process in group successfully \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Alert!!! Unable to send SIGINT signal to all process in the group \n";
    }

    /* Set SIGINT signal status to default */
    signal (SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    sleep(2);
```

I am not getting any error. But parent is getting killed. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: I don't see `SIG_IGN` anywhere in your code. Show a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error and is not compilable. After correcting that, I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
nPgid = getpgid(parentPID);
```

What is `parentPID`? The get the group of the calling process either pass `0` or the result of `getpid()`.

From `man getpgid()`:

> getpgid() returns the PGID of the process specified by pid.  If pid
>          is zero, the process ID of the calling process is used.  (Retrieving
>          the PGID of a process other than the caller is rarely necessary, and
>          the POSIX.1 getpgrp() is preferred for that task.)

From this text above I'd draw the conclusion to do

```
nPgid = getpgid(o);
```

Comment: Anyway i was able get group id for that process. giving sigint signal to entire group is happening. but eventhough i am giving SIG_IGN in parent process, it is also getting sigint signal and exiting. idont want parent process to exit.